# Отчеты в JMeter

Tags: java, jenkins, jmeter

Ребят, можете подсказать, если плагины/инструменты чтобы отчеты по JMeter более наглядно показывались. Вроде примерно разобрался как смотреть, но читал много что встроенный "отображатель" это фу.

+Также интересует вопрос - я хочу это все дело еще пустить крутиться в Jenkins:

1. Как cmd прописать это я понял, но это некрасиво - если я добавлю git
   то он оттуда сам(видел что надо прописать некий скрипт) будет
   забирать все тесты?
2. Касательно предыдущего вопроса, можно ли через 1 джобу настраивать запуск и 1,2 и т.д.(сколько нужно) тестов?
3. Есть ли отображатели для дженкинса(видел HTML publisher - Но сходу не понял - вроде надо в csv перегонять репорты).

Answer (score 1):

[Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) дает более-менее полную информацию

По поводу Jenkins:

1. Забрать скрипт(ы) с Git можно с помощью [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)
2. В случае с Freestyle Job - есть [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin), в случае с [Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) - есть [`build` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)
3. Для отображения результатов можно использовать Reporting Dashboard + HTML Publisher, но лучше посмотреть в сторону [Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) он добавляет на дашборд результаты, графики с трендами и может зафейлить билд если время отклика будет превышать заданное максимальное значение

Comment: с performance plugin и работаю, но думаю про наглядность, чтобы не только я смог понять.

Answer (score 1):

Я дополню ответ [@Dmitri T](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/251889/dmitri-t)

Можно еще influxdb + grafana подключить. D итоге получится очень красиво. Также можно в realtime посмотреть на графики, пока тесты выполняются. Это удобно, когда тесты слишком долгие.

**UPDATE**

Для Вас я создал [репозиторий](https://github.com/Tsovak/jmeter), который поможет для решения ваших проблем. Там уже описано как использовать, а в конце генерирует для вас отчет в виде HTML. 
Для генерации такого отчета, необходимо немного изменить `.config`-файлы, что уже уделано.

Вам нужно указать JMX-файл, 
запустить скрипт как `Execute shell`. Если нет ошибок, то `exit $FAIL_COUNT` будет 0 и job-а будет зеленой, если есть, то код возврата будет содержать количество ошщибок и job-а  зафейлится.

Вы подключаете HTML Publisher и после выполнения теста публикуете отчет.

Для того, чтобы запускать несколько job-ов, Вам нужно подключить  Parameterized Trigger Plugin, как сказал [@Dmitri T](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/251889/dmitri-t). 
Далее в `Build` выбираете `Multijob Phase`  и указываете название конкретной джобы. Его можно параметризовать неплохо, например, `Job execution type` позволяет несколько джобов запустить параллельно или последовательно.

Comment: тоже - да красивые графики. Но интересует именно вариация с Jenkins - чтобы там можно было сразу открыть наглядный отчет(тот же HTML Publisher). А grafana как я понял надо развертывать сервер и смотреть через нее, да круто - но нужно чтобы были отчеты(круто если такие же простые для понимания) в Jenkins'e сразу после прогонки тестов.

Comment: @sank я дополнил ответ, и надеюсь, что это поможет вам

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться, а можете подсказать(вдруг сталкивались), я вроде смог подрубить через HTML Publisher - все круто, но на компе у меня файл открывается, и все отображается, а в Jenkins не подгружаются js и css как я понял. Почитав все говорят что это CSP(https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy). Я пока просто не понял куда писать SystemProperty.

Comment: должно работать из под коробки. если инструкция, которую вы скинули - не поможет. то вам нужно развернуть nginx/ указать . в какую папку должно смотреть. а отчеты после теста копировать в папку nginx-а, скажем BUILD_NUMBER

Comment: спасибо, там и вправду если перезапустить jenkins в cmd с нужными параметрами то все начнет отображаться(начиная со следующих тестов).
И еще глупый вопрос - можно ли как-то указать чтобы после каждой прогонки тестов создавались новые папки - например с текущей датой и временем. вроде есть такой вариант @{BUILD_NUMBER} но не так пишу видимо.

П.С. перечитал ваш комментарий, а как в Jenkins они пишутся как я указал или по иному?

Comment: у каждого билда есть Environment variables, откуда можно достать BUILD_NUMBER. в sh/bash можно достать значение как $BUILD_NUMBER. скажем, nginx смотрит а папку /var/reports/. тогда выполните `mkdir $BUILD_NUMBER; cp results  /var/reports/$BUILD_NUMBER`.  номер папки должен совпадать с номером билда, чтобы легче было ориентироваться в будущем

Comment: это я понимаю для unix систем? У меня стоит на Windows.

Comment: нашел - %build_number%